# if文の別記法？の意味を教えてください。

Tags: java

以下の式のreturn以降の記法がわからなく困っています。

```
private String fm(float value) {
    return (value <=0) ? ""+value : "+"+value;
}
```

if文の一種かな？とは思っているのですがどういう記法かこのコードが乗っていた本にはなにも解説がないため検索もできません。
`?`以降が特にわかりませんので解説していただけると助かります。

Answer (score 6):

三項演算子といいます。

`(value <=0)?""+value:"+"+value` で一つのまとまりになり、

`(value <=0)` が条件文で、真なら`?`と`:`で囲まれた部分（ここでは`""+value`）、偽なら`:`以降（ここでは`"+"+value`）が返ります。

Comment: 補足(全体を見た時)：`(条件式) ? (真の処理) : (偽の処理)`

Comment: ありがとうございます！空の""が混乱の原因になっていました。シンプルな説明と補足、助かります。

Comment: この回答でよろしければ、[解決としてマーク]をクリックしてください（この質問が未解決となってしまうため）

Answer (score 3):

Java仕様としては [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) の "conditional operator"です。日本語だと[条件演算子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97%E5%AD%90)でしょうか。呼称として通りが良いのは[三項演算子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E9%A0%85%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97%E5%AD%90)の方かもしれません。

次の`if`文と等価です。

```
private String fm(float value) {
    if (value <=0) {
        return ""+value;
    } else {
        return "+"+value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！上のコメント見たあと、英語でなんて言うんだろうと思ったらバッチリの回答が！Conditional Operatorっていうんですね、勉強になります～

Comment: @Maria 他の呼び名だと、`inline if`、`iif`、`ternary operator`、`ternary if`などなど